# sort an array of struct alphabetically with names that have spaces

Tags: c, sorting, struct

i have a struct

```
struct BookInfo
{
    char title[50];
    int numAuthors;
    char authors[50][50];
    int year;
    int checkedout;
};
```

i can sorted by years  but i cannot get it to sort by titles for the life of me all my code does is print out the names in the order they are in the file or i get "incompatible types in assingment" errors for comented lines

```
int j,i;
    char temp;
    for(i = 1; i < 14; i++)
    {
        j = i - 1;
        while( j >= 0 && strcmp( library[j+1].title, library[j].title) < 0 )
        {
            temp =  library[j + 1]; /*errors*/
            library[j+1] = library[j];
            library[j] = temp; /*errors*/
            j--;
        }
        printf("n%s",library[j].title);
    }
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What type is library?

Comment: struct BookInfo library[500];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting `BookInfo` instances, so your `temp` variable should be of the same type instead of char:

```
int j,i;
BookInfo temp;
```

Comment: i put struct in front of BookInfo and it works but still does not sort the books

Comment: @Tatan1, that's a different matter. What do you mean by "does not sort"? Are they not sorted at all, or only partially, or in incorrect order?

Comment: not sorted at all...... all the names just print in the same order they are in the file it is reading

Comment: funny while im running the  program if i tell it to sorted again it sorts it so i guess my question would be how do i get it to work on the first try